# Empty object on return of instantiated object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I return a Gameobject when making a New Tetromino from the GameController but It is returning a empty object. The Log in the Spawner code is showing the right object, but the log in the gamecontroller is just showing Object.

Spawner code:

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] Tetrominoes;
    private List<GameObject> instantiatedTetrominioes = new List<GameObject>();
    private int index = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        NewTetromino();
    }

    public GameObject NewTetromino()
    {
       GameObject newObject =  Instantiate(Tetrominoes[Random.Range(0, Tetrominoes.Length)], transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        instantiatedTetrominioes.Add(newObject);
        index++;
        Debug.Log(instantiatedTetrominioes[index - 1]);
        return instantiatedTetrominioes[index - 1];
    }
}
```

Code in GameController:

```
void OnGameStarted()
{
    currentBlock = spawner.NewTetromino();
    Debug.Log("current: " + currentBlock);
}
```

Comment: You also call `NewTetromino` in `void Start` of `Spawner`. So maybe you see the log of the `Spawner.Start`->`NewTetromino` call, then when you call `spawner.NewTetromino` on `OnGameStarted` you get an empty debug log from `NewTetromino` and also an "empty" debug log from `OnGameStarted` (except it includes the text "current").

Comment: that might be the problem, thanks!